# cannot open LUKS patition as read only

Tags: lvm, backup, luks, readonly, disk-image

I have saved a whole disk image of a Debian Jessie in a image.img file using:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/usbdisk/image.img
```

This file is meant to be a backup of the whole disk. The whole partition was encrypted using LUKS during Debian installation.
Now I want to mount this disk image to access some content. I do it from a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I manage to do it in read-write as follows:

```
$ sudo kpartx -av /media/usbdisk/image.img  
add map loop24p1 (253:0): 0 497664 linear 7:27  2048  
add map loop24p2 (253:1): 0 2 linear 7:27 501758  
add map loop24p5 (253:2): 0 999712768 linear 7:27 501760  
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/dm-2 mylvm
```

I enter the passphrase and this works fine: I can now access the files in the mounted volume (debian-vg/root).

```
$ sudo dmsetup info -C
Name              Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID                                                                
mylvm             253   3 L--w    2    1      0 CRYPT-LUKS1-sometext-mylvm                  
loop24p2          253   1 L--w    0    1      0 part2-devnode_sometext                                          
loop24p1          253   0 L--w    0    1      0 part1-devnode_sometext                                          
debian--vg-root   253   4 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-sometext
loop24p5          253   2 L--w    1    1      0 part5-devnod_sometext                                          
debian--vg-swap_1 253   5 L--w    0    1      0 LVM-sometext
```

The problem is that the .img file changes as I access the mounted volume... which I don't want since this meant to be a readonly backup file.

So I try the same with --readonly flag

```
$ sudo cryptsetup --readonly luksOpen /dev/dm-2 mylvm
```

However in this case the mylvm is not mounted

```
$ sudo dmsetup info -C  
Name             Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID                                                
mylvm            253   3 L--r    0    1      0 CRYPT-LUKS1-sometext  
loop24p5         253   2 L--w    1    1      0 part5-devnode_sometext            
loop24p2         253   1 L--w    0    1      0 part2-devnode_sometext   
loop24p1         253   0 L--w    0    1      0 part1-devnode_sometext
```

I cannot see the debian--vg

How can I mount this image as readonly ?

Thanks

ag